# import-all-tables hanging in during hive-import

Tags: sqoop

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import-all-tables --connect="jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/dbname"
 --username=xxx --password=yyy -m 1 --hive-import --hive-overwrite 
--create-hive-table --hive-database sqoopimport --hive-home /user/hive/warehouse
```

It is running upto map-reduce and during hive import it is hanging in below step, am I doing any mistake?

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.7.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

Full log:

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/08/13 21:20:37 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.7.0
16/08/13 21:20:37 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/08/13 21:20:37 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
16/08/13 21:20:37 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
16/08/13 21:20:38 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/08/13 21:20:39 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/08/13 21:20:39 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/08/13 21:20:39 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/08/13 21:20:39 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/af1ef62229d717800a3cd16b42f53dc3/categories.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/08/13 21:20:43 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/af1ef62229d717800a3cd16b42f53dc3/categories.jar
16/08/13 21:20:43 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
16/08/13 21:20:43 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
16/08/13 21:20:43 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
16/08/13 21:20:43 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
16/08/13 21:20:43 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of categories
16/08/13 21:20:44 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
16/08/13 21:20:45 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16/08/13 21:20:46 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032
16/08/13 21:20:49 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
16/08/13 21:20:49 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/08/13 21:20:49 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1470828230815_0030
16/08/13 21:20:50 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1470828230815_0030
16/08/13 21:20:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1470828230815_0030/
16/08/13 21:20:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1470828230815_0030
16/08/13 21:21:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1470828230815_0030 running in uber mode : false
16/08/13 21:21:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/08/13 21:21:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/08/13 21:21:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1470828230815_0030 completed successfully
16/08/13 21:21:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=139452
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=1029
        HDFS: Number of read operations=4
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=1
        Other local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1008512
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=7879
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=7879
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=1008512
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=58
        Map output records=58
        Input split bytes=87
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=78
        CPU time spent (ms)=950
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=143511552
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=726700032
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=48234496
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=1029
16/08/13 21:21:18 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 1.0049 KB in 32.6366 seconds (31.5291 bytes/sec)
16/08/13 21:21:18 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 58 records.
16/08/13 21:21:18 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/08/13 21:21:18 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.7.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

Comment: **Hanging** during hive import

Comment: I am using CDH 5.7 distribution from cloudera